# how to switch scripts used, based on runner tag

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have 3 different gitlab-ci runners,serving different tags ('linux', 'darwin', and 'windows'). I need to setup a .gitlab-ci.yml file, so that if I run a job on darwin it will execute darwin script, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags) are for; the canonical example suggests just your use case, reproduced here;

```
windows job:
  stage:
    - build
  tags:
    - windows
  script:
    - echo Hello, %USERNAME%!

osx job:
  stage:
    - build
  tags:
    - osx
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $USER!"
```